# Does $|\hat{\theta}_n|-|\theta|=o_p(\alpha_n)$ implies $\hat{\theta}_n-\theta=o_p(\alpha_n)$

Tags: asymptotics

Does $|\hat{\theta}_n|-|\theta|=o_p(\alpha_n)$ implies $\hat{\theta}_n-\theta=o_p(\alpha_n)$? ($\alpha_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$)

Comment: $\hat{\theta}_n = (-1)^n \theta$?

Comment: Alternative counterexample: $\hat{\theta}_n = -\theta = 1$, $\alpha_n=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it doesn't, as a counterexample, $\theta_n = -5$ for all $n$, $\theta = 5$. Then first equation is always zero, but the implication doesn't hold.